# How can i improve my method for creating models with their internal ID as key?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have built a backend for an iOS app with Google App Engine running python 2.7. When i create objects i want the backend to give it an ID which can be used by all clients as the one identifier to query. This method i use involves two put and basically just used since i was using db instead of ndb. Is there a better way of inserting objects and giving them an easily accessable Integer ID?

```
class Player(ndb.Model):
     playerID = ndb.IntegerProperty()
     username = db.StringProperty()

class createUserWithUsername(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    username = self.request.get('username')  
    playerArr = Player.query(Player._properties["username"] == username).fetch(1)
        if len(playerArr) > 0:
            self.error(500)
        else:
            newPlayer = Player()
            newPlayer.username = username
            key = newPlayer.put()
            newPlayer.playerID = key.id()
            newPlayer.put()
   # returning player as dict to client
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to query the ID and then save it back as a separate property? Why not just use it directly to get the player?

```
player_key = ndb.Key(Player, id)
player = player_key.get()
```

Comment: Oh sorry, i had pasted the wrong method. Basically i have a method that sets the queried ID as the ID, but when i create a player based on username, i want to give it an backend-generated ID which i give to client. For example if i sign up a player using his Facebook account its based on username, and i won't have a ID. This then needs to be generated by the backend

Comment: Well, but that's my point, the key always has an ID so you can just use that.

Comment: What is the id variable? i get this: Key id must be a string or a number; received <built-in function id>

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way you can assign a key of your choosing, in just one put operation. Replace the constructor you have in your "else" clause with this one.

The "id" property will give the entity whatever key you assign it, much like "key_name" does in the old DB.

```
newPlayer = Player(
    username=username,
    id = # the key of your choosing
    )
NewPlayer.put()
```

You'll also need a way to generate unique keys for each of your entities, but I trust you have that part figured out already.

Good luck!

Comment: No, i want to let the datastore create the IDs, then i don't have to check if any ids are taken before assigning them.